# Ingreso de variables en Query o Mutation graphql-php

Tags: graphql

Al realizar una simple consulta e ingresar el id del usuario, me genera un error que dice que la variable no es proporcionada.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Si ingreso la variable directamente no tengo ningún error, lo que quiere decir que mi Back-end esta haciendo bien su trabajo.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Agradezco la ayuda que me puedan brindar.
Saludos!!

Comment: GraphiQL a veces es muy estricto en la forma en la que espera que le des formato a las variables. En la imagen que pones se aprecia que la primara línea está vacía y luego empiezas tu declaración de variables. Prueba primero declarando todo en una sola línea: {"input": 3}. Después empieza a darle formato con cuidado a ver si sigue funcionando.

Comment: Ya conseguí solucionar el problema, después de tanto probar dependencias de autentificación logre configurar mi user para que generar un token cuando se logea, para eso utilice el package larevel\passport,.

Comment: Adjunto enlace del artículo que me ayudo a solucionar mi problema https://lighthouse-php-auth.com/tutorials/getting-started/